# Intellij <style rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css">

Tags: intellij-idea

When I use:

```
<style rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css"> ... </style>
```

in intellij, I am getting lots of errors. It seems as if it is not recognizing this syntax. I am using a html file for this tag.

Comment: Is the LESS plugin installed? You can find it under Settings > Plugins > LESS support. However, I don't get any errors with your code, although I'm not using that plugin.

Comment: Yes, it is installed. Are you using nested rules? For instance like this: http://pastebin.com/rLSpXMgp

Comment: You're right. It seems that the plugin only works within .less files. So you need to put your LESS code into a separate file and include it using <link>. Since it is a Jetbrains plugin, I would recommend to create a ticket/feature request to include a support for inline LESS support.

Comment: @DarekKay But I am trying to move it out from the file into context. I will try to add a ticket soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following code worked for me

```html
  <style type="text/less">
  
  </style>
```

However, the attached less file does not see the variable

```html
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/less" href="index.less" />
```

To use variables. You can use the syntax

```html
<script>
    less={globalVars: {'color_root': '#fff'}
};
</script>
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

[Learn More](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser-options)